# AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'", u'occurred at index Identifier 1') and other problems

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an AttributeError when I try to pass a dataframe to a function I created.

I have a function that I created that is supposed to do some basic operations on a row from a dataframe I am passing but only if one of the cells contains a certain value. First post sorry if its long. Here is relevant code and error.

```
nitrogen.head()

    Identifier 1       Amount   Area 28  Percent Nitrogen d 15N/14N   d15N
0   sediment standard  1.568    23.478   0                -4.046      0
1   sediment standard  1.801    11.230   0                3.660       0
2   sediment standard  1.554    9.591    0                3.391       0
3   1c-50cm            12.322   36.075   0                4.349       0
4   1c-10cm            11.786   35.296   0                5.622       0

def correctNitrogen(data):
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if data.loc[index, 'Identifier 1'] == 'sediment standard':
            standardsP += (data['Amount']/data['Area 28'])*0.62
            standardsD += data['d 15N/14N']
            x += 1

    averageP = standardsP/x
    averageD = standardsD/x
    correcter = 4.42-averageD

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if data.loc[index, 'Identifier 1'] != 'sediment standard':
             data['Percent Nitrogen'] = averageP*(data['Area 28']/data['Amount'])
             data['d15N'] = data['d 15N/14N']+correcter

nitrogen.apply(correctNitrogen)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-98f6b563e9b6> in <module>()
----> 1 nitrogen.apply(correctNitrogen)
      2 nitrogen.head()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4260                         f, axis,
   4261                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4262                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4263             else:
   4264                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4356             try:
   4357                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4358                     results[i] = func(v)
   4359                     keys.append(v.name)
   4360             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-157-ff5a7f145cc2> in correctNitrogen(data)
      2 # corrects it to the standard that is being used
      3 def correctNitrogen(data):
----> 4     for index, row in data.iterrows():
      5         if data.loc[index, 'Identifier 1'] == 'sediment standard':
      6             standardsP += (data['Amount']/data['Area 28'])*nit

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3079             if name in self._info_axis:
   3080                 return self[name]
-> 3081             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3082 
   3083     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'", u'occurred at index Identifier 1')
```

Now I realize that there may be other problems with the function but this is the first that I have run into so far. I feel like it has something to do with how I am passing the dataframe to the function but I don't know how to fix it..

Comment: Try nitrogen = correctNitrogen(nitrogen) and return data from your function

Comment: @run-out his function is not returning a dataframe.

Comment: @ajnLJA-0184 You make a good point. Your solution will work as well, I just am in the habit of passing local variables when dealing with functions directly to avoid any pitfalls in adjusting globally inside a function. I suggested he return 'data' and make it equal to nitrogen.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - the function `apply` is called on a column/row, which is a `pandas.Series` thus you have the error.

To fix without modifying your function, call:

```
nitrogen = correctNitrogen(nitrogen)
```

But also note you need to return the DataFrame from the function:

```
def correctNitrogen(data):
    # do stuff
    return data
```